# Every time i open my pc i am asked to install ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-one

When the bootable pendrive is inserted option is asked if ubuntu should be installed or try ubuntu but if pendrive is not connected a message appears claiming no bootable drive found
As a result every time i start my pc i need to install it 
Plz help !

Comment: Did you manage to actually install ubuntu on your PC?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your BIOS is set to boot from USB rather than your internal hard disk.

You need to know how to configure your BIOS to change the boot device. If you still have the motherboard or computer manual then the information on setting a boot device will be in there.

If you don't have this you can find the make and model of you motherboard from Linux:

1) Boot into Linux from your USB drive;

2) Open a terminal with CTRL-ALT-F2;

3) Enter this command (you will need your password)

```
sudo lshw | more
```

4) Look for lines similar to this:

```
   *-core:
      description: Motherboard
      product: FM2A88X Extreme6+
      vendor: ASRock
```

So I have an ASRock FM2A88X Extreme6+, and I can go to their website to download the user guide.

5) Close the Terminal.